# What Cocoa view does iTunes use to display the library panel?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

What Cocoa view does iTunes use to display the library panel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by Library you mean Sidebar - it's `NSOutlineView` with "Source List" as highlight setting.